# Problems with my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits bootable USB

Tags: boot, 14.04, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 in my computer by using a bootable USB but I keep getting this error:

```
SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C)...
Unkown keyword in configuration file: =J(triangle)
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot: _
```